# How to deserialize complex JSON with a date as a key C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am giving up on this.
I've got the following Json that I need to deserialize:

```
json = "{
      "2018-05-21": {
        "lastUpdate": "2018-05-21 01:00:05",
        "stops": [
          {
            "stopId": 1838,
            "stopCode": "02"
    }, {
            "stopId": 1839,
            "stopCode": "08"
    }]}}";

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StopDate>(json); // null
```

and those classes:

```
public class StopDate
{
    public BusStop date { get; set; }
}
public class BusStop
{
    public string LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public Stop[] Stops { get; set; }
}
public class Stop
{
    public int StopId { get; set; }
    public string StopName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that deserialized variable is null.

Apart from the overall ugliness when it comes to the names etc, I'd like it to be up and running just for a good start. All help's appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the JSON to a `Dictionary<DateTime, BusStop>`

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<DateTime, BusStop>>(json);
```

The `DateTime` key of the dictionary maps to the date in the JSON.

If the `DateTime` causes any issue then use a `string` as the key, ie `Dictionary<string, BusStop>` where the key can be parsed into a `DateTime` is needed

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, BusStop>>(json);
BusStop busStop = deserialized["2018-05-21"];
```

And you probably want to make `LastUpdate` a `DateTime` rather than a `string` (*as suggested by a commenter*)

```
public class BusStop {
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public Stop[] Stops { get; set; }
}

public class Stop {
    public int StopId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("stopCode")]
    public string StopName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And you probably want to make LastUpdate a DateTime rather than a string.

Comment: @Nkosi, your solution rocks! Big thanks! Thanks both for hints.